# How to make Proguard to obfuscate jars within a jar file

Tags: java, jar, ant, proguard

I have a run-able java jar file let's call it `masterProgram.jar`.
Inside this `masterProgram.jar` if I extract it using 7Zip or WinRAR there are other jars, lets call it `lib1.jar, lib2.jar`.

Proguard managed to obfuscated  the master jar, but when I look-inside the lib jars are not. and because of this the program (masterProgram.jar) breaks at a certain point. I also already set `overloadaggressively` option in my condig.

I'm calling the proguard.jar through an ant build.xml.
and here is my config file `config.proguard`

```
-injars 'masterProgram.jar'

-target 1.7
-dontshrink

-dontoptimize
-allowaccessmodification
-printmapping dataprintmap.txt
-overloadaggressively
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-repackageclasses ''
-keepattributes Exceptions,Innerclasses,Signature,Deprecated,*Annotation*,Synthetic
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-dontnote
-printseeds dataseed.txt
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
```

Comment: Jars inside jars are not really how jars are supposed to work.

Comment: Noted. But lets just say its a legacy piece of software.

Comment: Even so, you'll need to rearrange things to make ProGuard able to deal with things.  ProGuard has no way to deal with jars in jars because that's not how jars are intended to be used.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you. I have re-arranged the code so that there is no jars inside another jar. ProGuard managed to obfuscate it for me. Could you please move your comment to answer so I can vote it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jars inside jars are not really how jars are supposed to work.  You'll need to rearrange things to make ProGuard able to deal with things. ProGuard has no way to deal with jars in jars because that's not how jars are intended to be used.