# How to obfuscate multi-module spring-boot project with proguard?

Tags: java, spring-boot, proguard, multi-module, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I tried to compile  and obfuscate 2 projects where the one depends on the other one and both are built with the Spring boot maven plugin.

Let's call them for the sake of simplicity main and util projects.

The build has two stages. In the first stage the util project is built. In the second stage the main project which depends on the util project.

My problem is that Spring boot maven plugin creates nested jars. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)

So if I try first repackage the projects with Spring boot maven plugin and after that obfuscate the repackaged jar which contains both the util and the main projects, then first proguard extracts the repackaged jar's content where the extracted content will contain the util jar. Then proguard won't obfuscate the content of this util jar because it is a jar and not a set of class files.

If I try first obfuscate the util project with proguard and after that repackaging with Spring boot maven plugin then the obfuscation will be done but when I try to compile the main project then it won't find the necessary symbols in the jar produced from the util project.

So how to obfuscate projects repackaged with Spring boot maven project?

Comment: It could be helpful to post your proguard configuration.

Comment: Maybe the proguard configuration is not so important. The more important part is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237045/how-to-make-proguard-to-obfuscate-jars-within-a-jar-file). This is why the obfuscation doesn't work in case if Spring boot maven plugin is used for repackaging.

Answer (score 4):

In your main module declare proguard-maven-plugin and spring-boot-maven-plugin (proguard package phase must be executed before spring boot plugin repackage goal). Declare it only in module which is entry point - no need to declare it in submodules or parent pom.

Then, in your proguard plugin config add modules which you would like to obfuscate besides main jar:

```
             <configuration>
                <assembly>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.yourgroupid</groupId>
                            <artifactId>submodule</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </assembly>
                ...
```

And in spring-boot-maven-plugin add exclusion, so spring not overwrites already obfuscated jar:

```
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>
                    com.yourapp.App
                </mainClass>
                <excludeGroupIds>com.yourgroupid</excludeGroupIds>
            </configuration>
```

Hope that it will work for you!

Comment: Thx a billion. You saved me!